# Scipy Minimize, can the inverse hessian be used to eliminate multiple solutions with similar "fun"?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scipy-optimize

Let's say you have a minimization problem:

```
data_set_1=[[24.714, 24.713, 24.605, 24.607], [25.708, 25.59, 25.557, 25.753], [22.713, 22.654, 22.655, 22.812], [24.231, 24.233, 24.289, 24.109], [24.401, 24.385, 24.396, 24.408], [26.124, 26.107, 25.915, 25.847], [15.341, 15.242, 15.049, 14.847], [22.332, 22.282, 22.324, 22.314], [25.843, 25.835, 25.683, 25.983], [24.4, 24.402, 24.522, 24.409], [20.218, 20.23, 20.212, 20.254], [21.927, 21.955, 21.94, 21.917], [20.697, 20.705, 20.731, 20.692], [21.13, 21.134, 21.196, 21.266], [24.619, 24.55, 24.556, 24.784], [25.294, 25.29, 25.322, 25.337], [24.237, 24.124, 24.06, 24.143], [18.533, 18.603, 18.814, 19.229], [26.235, 26.183, 26.226, 26.137], [25.754, 25.72, 25.658, 25.639], [26.786, 26.716, 26.646, 26.668], [23.863, 23.838, 23.946, 24.034], [21.402, 21.395, 21.401, 21.317], [22.382, 22.386, 22.363, 22.244], [22.435, 22.454, 22.434, 22.579], [20.416, 20.444, 20.439, 20.583], [24.929, 24.943, 24.819, 24.916], [25.839, 25.811, 25.716, 25.752]]

data_set_2=[[0.786, 0.781, 0.766, 0.773], [0.78, 0.773, 0.782, 0.798], [0.983, 0.993, 0.991, 1.031], [0.74, 0.741, 0.756, 0.695], [0.614, 0.608, 0.642, 0.646], [0.659, 0.67, 0.666, 0.675], [0.488, 0.456, 0.438, 0.571], [0.99, 0.979, 0.97, 0.959], [0.806, 0.815, 0.801, 0.818], [0.772, 0.772, 0.756, 0.752], [0.364, 0.373, 0.357, 0.394], [0.735, 0.727, 0.729, 0.705], [0.489, 0.484, 0.495, 0.462], [0.803, 0.806, 0.817, 0.831], [1.018, 1.02, 1.021, 0.993], [0.589, 0.606, 0.599, 0.622], [0.61, 0.612, 0.591, 0.615], [0.973, 0.955, 0.94, 0.956], [0.628, 0.634, 0.643, 0.669], [0.64, 0.656, 0.637, 0.619], [0.732, 0.738, 0.742, 0.743], [0.872, 0.865, 0.859, 0.838], [0.199, 0.205, 0.21, 0.221], [0.783, 0.771, 0.775, 0.727], [1.069, 1.075, 1.064, 1.1], [0.707, 0.708, 0.705, 0.741], [1.07, 1.061, 1.058, 1.034], [0.911, 0.908, 0.91, 0.888]]

def get_populations(initial,io):
 k,k1,x,y=initial[0],initial[1],initial[2],initial[3]
 kx,k1x=k*x,k1*x
 ky,k1y=k*y,k1*y
 kxy,k1xy=k*x*y,k1*x*y
 pF=(np.sqrt((k*k1)**2+(8*io*k*k1)+(8*io*k*k1**2))-(k*k1))/(4*(1+k1))
 pC=(((4*io)+(4*io*k1))/(4*(1+k1)**2))-(pF/(1+k1))
 pO=k1*pC
 pF2=(np.sqrt((kx*k1x)**2+(8*io*kx*k1x)+(8*io*kx*k1x**2))-(kx*k1x))/(4*(1+k1x))
 pC2=(((4*io)+(4*io*k1x))/(4*(1+k1x)**2))-(pF2/(1+k1x))
 pO2=k1x*pC2
 pF3=(np.sqrt((ky*k1y)**2+(8*io*ky*k1y)+(8*io*ky*k1y**2))-(ky*k1y))/(4*(1+k1y))
 pC3=(((4*io)+(4*io*k1y))/(4*(1+k1y)**2))-(pF3/(1+k1y))
 pO3=k1y*pC3
 pF4=(np.sqrt((kxy*k1xy)**2+(8*io*kxy*k1xy)+(8*io*kxy*k1xy**2))-(kxy*k1xy))/(4*(1+k1xy))
 pC4=(((4*io)+(4*io*k1xy))/(4*(1+k1xy)**2))-(pF4/(1+k1xy))
 pO4=k1xy*pC4
 local_chi2=0
 for data1,data2 in zip(data_set_1,data_set_2):
   populations=np.array([[pF,pO,pC],[pF2,pO2,pC2],[pF3,pO3,pC3],[pF4,pO4,pC4]])
   least_squared_fit_1=lsmr(populations/io,np.array([data1])/4*800,maxiter=10)
   least_squared_fit_2=lsmr(populations/io,np.array([data2])*800,maxiter=10)
   local_chi2+=least_squared_fit_1[3]**2+least_squared_fit_2[3]**2
 return local_chi2

global_parameter_solution=minimize(get_populations,args=io, x0=np.array([2e3,2e-3,9,2e1]),bounds=np.array([[0,np.inf],[0,np.inf],[0,np.inf],[0,np.inf]]),options={'maxiter':100000})
```

Unfortunately, the landscape for this problem is quite flat, so there are multiple solutions. I'm looking at 2 particular solutions using 2 initial guesses.

Solution using 5e2,2e-2,7,3e1

```
message: CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH
  success: True
   status: 0
      fun: 1568.1943235398385
        x: [ 5.000e+02  1.226e-02  6.638e+00  3.039e+01]
      nit: 8
      jac: [-2.683e-03 -1.183e-01 -2.933e-03 -1.796e-03]
     nfev: 50
     njev: 10
 hess_inv: <4x4 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
```

With inverse hessian diagonal of

```
[0.99964765 0.00841953 1.41597902 3.25752296]
```

Solution 2 using 2e3,2e-3,9,2e1

```
message: CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH
  success: True
   status: 0
      fun: 1568.1943236577647
        x: [ 2.000e+03  9.445e-03  6.398e+00  2.838e+01]
      nit: 24
      jac: [-1.137e-04  1.100e-01 -1.000e-03 -1.523e-03]
     nfev: 370
     njev: 74
 hess_inv: <4x4 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
```

with inverse hessian

```
[1.00008883e+00 2.07424141e-03 5.98621521e+01 6.83255242e+01]
```

The "fun", or sum of residuals for both solutions is basically identical. However, the variance (the diagonal of the inverse hessian), for one solution is significantly worse than the other. Can I eliminate solution number 2 on the basis that the variance for one of the parameters is erronously high and thus the other solution is the valid one?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no free lunch here. Unless you can bring any more details to the situation both solutions would be equally viable.
For example, is one solution physically preferred, or are there bounds or constraints you could place on the parameters.

The two solutions don't look all that different, apart from the first parameter. Perhaps you should plot how `get_populations` varies as a function of the first parameter?

<disclaimer - I didn't look into the code in detail>

Comment: But the variance for one is reasonable while the other isn't? Can't that be used as a criteria?

Comment: No, I don't think so

Comment: They have the same likelihood.

Comment: Would you be cool to chat? I just wanted to ensure that I have the math translated into python correctly (maybe I get infinite solutions because I wrote the code incorrectly)

Comment: sorry, don't have the time to do that. I recommend looking at how chi2 varies for each of the parameters to get a better idea of your energy landscape. Also, formatting your code will make it easier for you to understand and process.

Comment: Formatting it further? Do you mean the equations? Because it appears quite straight forward to me?

Comment: Run your code through the `black` code formatter and you'll see what I mean.